# Oracle SQL: How to select the last available value in a month?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a series of daily data, though values are not available for all days. And I want to select the last value of every month, and match the date to the end day of that month. If no observations are available for that month, add the month to the result and return null.

For example, the original table is:

```
AS_OF_DATE                      DAILYAVG
24-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 71.61
29-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 59.26
30-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 57.29
31-OCT-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 55.44
22-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 0
27-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 0
29-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 0
15-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 195.83
28-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 537.83
29-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 519.28
30-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 501.97
31-JAN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 485.78
06-FEB-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 119.79
07-FEB-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 79.86
28-FEB-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 588.28
31-MAR-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM 2315.56
```

And I want my code to return:

```
DATES         MONAVG
31-OCT-13   55.44
30-NOV-13   0
31-DEC-13   NULL
31-JAN-14   485.78
28-FEB-14   588.28
31-MAR-14   2315.56
```

My current code is following:

```
select b.dates, monavg from
    (select
       distinct last_day(as_of_date) as dates,
       last_value(dailyavg) over (partition by trunc(AS_OF_DATE, 'mon')) as monavg -- something wrong in this line
     from(
          select 
              as_of_date,
              sum(AVG_BALANCE_USD) as dailyavg
          from BALANCES
          group by as_of_date)) a
     right join (select distinct last_day(as_of_date) as dates from BALANCES) b --this is a table of the right dates
     on a.dates=b.dates
order by dates;
```

The code runs, but it is returning the wrong values.

My data is pretty huge, so it is not easy to post how my results look like. And I was not able to find out why got the wrong values...

Can someone figure out what is wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the create table statement for your table?

Comment: And from where did it came the `31-DEC-13   NULL`

Comment: `31-DEC-13   NULL` comes from the `right join` clause. The original table? It is directly pulled from the datebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first create a subset of last days per month (tip: use the connect by trick or create a "dates" table)
2. then create a subset of the last daily average per month (max(daily_avg) keep (dense_rank ..) )
3. then left join the 2 subsets

also try indentation for your queries. It greatly improves readability.

edit:

```
1st subset: month, last_day
2nd subset: month, last_average

select last_day
,      last_average 
from 
(
    subset1
) 
left join 
(
    subset2
) using (month)
```

Comment: Great! `max() keep(dense_rank last)` works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select to_char( dates, 'dd-mon-yy' ) dates, 
       trunc(aveg,2) average
  from ( select max(t.AS_OF_DATE) DATES,
                b.aveg
           from test t,
                (select extract(month from AS_OF_DATE) mon, 
                        extract(year from AS_OF_DATE) y, 
                        avg(DAILYAVG) aveg
                   from test t
                  group by extract(month from AS_OF_DATE), 
                           extract(year from AS_OF_DATE)
                 ) b
 where extract(month from t.AS_OF_DATE) = b.mon
   and extract(year from t.AS_OF_DATE) = b.y
   group by b.aveg )
order by 1
```

see it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0529e/17